# Delete from SQL database when closing an alert in a PHP view

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a project where I want to display notifications to a user when they log into the dashboard.  The notifications are passed into the view and displayed like this:

```
                <div class="box-body">
                <?php foreach ($notifications as $notification) {?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                            <strong><?php echo $notification->getNotificationTitle();?></strong> 
                            <?php echo $notification->getNotificationDescription();?>

                        </div>
                <?php }?>
        </div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is finding a way in which the notification can then be deleted from the database if the alert is dismissed.  I am using codeigniter and a MySQL database.

Comment: you'd need JS code to detect the dismissal, then send an ajax request to the server to tell it to delete the associated record. php itself cannot do this, because it's purely a server-side thing, and cannot detect what you do on the client, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own custom popup with two buttons. Let's call them Approve and Dismiss. And by using AJAX you can make a request to delete the record using it's id from the database. You display a delete anchor in the foreach loop giving it the id of that record. Let's say:

```
<a id='record_here_goes_the_id' class='record_delete_btn'>
```

And the on click of that you show the popup and also get the id from the same button you clicked, something like:

```js
$('.record_delete_btn').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.replace('record_', '');//and now you have the id of the record you want to delete, just put in somewhere to get it for your AJAX request
});
```

You can put the id in hidden input or another hidden element. Just pass the id you just got above and do your AJAX request based on that:

```js
$('#dismiss').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //here goes your $.ajax request
});
$('#approve').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //here you hide the popup and do nothing, ex: $('.popup').hide();
});
```

```html
<div class='popup'>
  <p>What are you going to do?</p>
  <a id='dismiss'>Dismiss</a>
  <a id='approve'>Approve</a>
</div>
```

You make a AJAX request to your PHP file where you will delete the record on click of dismiss button.
Something like this should do. Of course you will have to style your popup and everything else using CSS. And on page load hide the popup.